# I want to convert Object list to json array in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to convert the a `List<Object>` to a `List<List<dynamic>>` and send it as JSON to an API.

Here is my Object model class `CartMapModel`:

```dart
class CartMapModel { 
  String itemName;
  String itemPrice;
  String itemDescription;
  
  CartMapModel({this.itemDescription,this.itemPrice,this.itemName});
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "itemName": itemName,
      "itemPrice": itemPrice,
      "itemDescription" : itemDescription
    };
  }
}
```

Here is my `List<CartMapModel>`:

```dart
cartOrderList.add(
  CartMapModel(
    itemPrice: itmPrice.toString(),
    itemName: itmName,
    itemDescription: itmDesc,
  )
);
```

I want to convert it to a `List<List<dynamic>>`:

```json
[
  [
    "Item Name 1",
    "123",
    "Item 1 Description"
  ],
  [
    "Item Name 2",
    "456",
    "Item 2 Description"
  ],
  [
    "Item Name 3",
    "789",
    "Item 3 Description"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonDataList =
    cartOrderList.map((cartOrder) => cartOrder.toJson().values.toList()).toList();
```

Comment: No it's converting it in map. I don't need map. Actually I want to remove keys of map want just values in array you can see the example array above